# moving data from a smart contract to a local drive

Tags: solidity, storage

is it possible to copy data from smart contract to a local drive??
 ie, suppose I created a smart contract and i wish to copy the available data at the storage to my local drive... Is there any possible way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: what if i want to update my contract without loosing data??@RaghavSood

Comment: You would usually build that functionality into the contract, or use a proxy system if you want to update the code itself.

Comment: so is it possible to store data in a local storage rather than the Blockchain storage.??(useful for situation where large data need to be stored in blockchain)  @RaghavSood

Comment: Your smart contract cannot access data outside the blockchain, unless you use something like an oracle. You would usually store hashes and pointers to the data on ipfs/swarm/http if you need to store something large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the ways mentioned here, another way to do this is by using events in solidity. Fire an event, every time a transaction happens that changes your data variables. Watch for those events on your front-end and add them to wherever you want to store them